# Third-party authentication in a modeless dialog of a Google Sheets add-on

Tags: authentication, google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I have a Microsoft Excel add-in. When launching, it opens a sidebar. The sidebar hosts a website which is the core of the add-in. The website can interact with the contents of the workbook. In one webpage, users can sign in. And there are two third-party authentication buttons: Microsoft and Google. Clicking on one button opens a [Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins) where users can enter their Microsoft/Google credentials, if succeeded, the dialog will be closed automatically.

I started to code a Google Sheets add-on for similar usage. When launching, it opens a modeless dialog (rather than a sidebar that most add-ons launch) by [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showmodelessdialoguserinterface,-title). The dialog hosts the website which is the core of the add-on. The website can interact with the contents of the workbook.

Now, I'm thinking of how to enable the 2 third-party authentication buttons for Microsoft and Google. There is no `Office.js` any more. Is opening another dialog on top of the modeless dialog a conventional way of hosting third-party authentication? Should I use [showModalDialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You shouldn't use `dialog`s or sidebars for authentication. You should open a separate webpage using `window.open` or similar methods. This is because all dialogs and sidebars are sandboxed in a iframe. Oauth will be disabled inside iframes for security.